# Get Parent control of context menu Windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have Context Menu when hold to grid

```
<Grid Tag="1" Tap="Grid_Tap" Style="{StaticResource GridMedium}">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/Assets/Images/Page/bg_haivl.png"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
        <toolkit:ContextMenu>
            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="pin to start" Tap="MenuItem_Tap"/>
        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
    <Image Source="/Assets/Images/Page/icon_haivl.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="94" Margin="0,14,0,0" />
    <Image Source="/Assets/Images/Page/logo_haivl.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="32" Margin="8,0,0,10" />
</Grid>
```

How can I get `<Grid Tag="1" Tap="Grid_Tap" Style="{StaticResource GridMedium}"></Grid>` by code behide MenuItem_Tap event

```
private void MenuItem_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem)sender;
    //...Select Grid here
}
```

Comment: did u try ((MenuItem)sender).Parent

Comment: Why don't you add `x:Name` into your grid and us it to get the grid from anywhere you need it?

Comment: I have more grids like this, but I want to 1 event MenuItem_Tap for 4 grids in my application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Please find the link for attached project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qgepayerhocczv5/TestProject.zip)

I created a sample application for you. Please check the one I attached and if you still have any other issues update your issues as comments.

Also if you are satisfied with the answer provided. Please mark it as answered.

Rakesh R

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid x:Name ="MyGrid" Tag="1" Tap="Grid_Tap" Style="{StaticResource GridMedium}">
<Grid.Background>
    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/Assets/Images/Page/bg_haivl.png"/>
</Grid.Background>
<toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
    <toolkit:ContextMenu>
        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="pin to start" Tap="MenuItem_Tap"/>
    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
</toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
<Image Source="/Assets/Images/Page/icon_haivl.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="94" Margin="0,14,0,0" />
<Image Source="/Assets/Images/Page/logo_haivl.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="32" Margin="8,0,0,10" />
```

```
private void MenuItem_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem)sender;

    //MyGrid.  // Access you grid here..
}
```

Comment: No, I use MenuItem_Tap event for more grids. In my application I have 5 grids like this, they were told apart by property Tag

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve for?

Comment: I want to get grid from menuItem, I try to get parrent of MenuItem, it  return ContectMenu, I get parent of ContextMenu it return Canvas, parent of Canvas is Popup. How cant I get grid by MenuItem. Please Help me!